# Morava K-theory of loop spaces of spheres

Tags: reference-request, at.algebraic-topology

Some time ago I cam across the paper "What we still don't know about loop spaces of spheres" by Ravenel:
https://people.math.rochester.edu/faculty/doug/mypapers/loop.pdf
which concerns computing Morava K-theory of loop spaces of spheres. In particular, he is giving a couple of conjectures concerning Spanier-Whitehead duals of Snaith summands, which in result should give an idea on computing the aforementioned Morava K-theory.

I wanted to ask if anybody knows what is the current state of art on these problems?

Comment: At least the strongest of Ravenel's conjectures is false, as first observed by Langsetmo.  Brantner, Knudsen and I give some references at the end of Section 6.5 of https://arxiv.org/abs/1908.11321

Comment: The paper of mine that he cites, which tells you a lot about these dual Snaith summands, and certain telescopes among them (Ravenel's $\tilde K_m$'s), was published in Progress in Mathematics, vol. 196 (2001).  My paper has its own intriguing conjectures, alluded to by Ravenel.